# Java: String: Is there a better way to compare Strings

Tags: java, swing

I feel curious this morning and was wandering if somebody had a better way to do this

```
if(TAG_PLAY.equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand())
   ||TAG_PASSWORD.equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand())
   ||...
){
```

I'm having a hunch that this could be improved by doing something like 
creating 1 big string and looking for e.getActionCommand() in it
but I don't know if it would be more efficient

Note: this has nothing to do with the getActionCommand, I'm purely interested in the logic, performance and new ways/patterns to do the same thing

---

Edit: I'm not considering the debate of upper and lower case^^

---

Edit:

How about this:

```
s = TAG_PLAY+","+TAG_PASSWORD;
//compareToIgnoreCase is not optimal since it will go through all the String
    if(0!=s.compareToIgnoreCase(anotherString)){
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you considered using Set.contains(Object)?

For example:

```
  Set<String> cases = new HashSet<String>();
  cases.add( TAG_PLAY.toLowerCase() );
  cases.add( TAG_PASSWORD.toLowerCase() );

  ...
  if ( cases.contains( e.getActionCommand().toLowerCase() ) { 
  ...
```

Comment: If adding is guaranteed not to add duplicates (or even if it is -- no matter here as `contains` just needs to find one), then an `[Array]List` will function just as well. One "advantage" to use a List (vs. a Set) is `Arrays.asList(TAG_PLAY.toLowerCase(), TAG_PADDWORD, ....)`. Personally I'm put off with the duplication of `toLowerCase`, but Java sadly lacks a[n easy] "map" construct. For trivial n, the O(n) vs. O(1) debate is largely is irrelevant here.

Comment: You can also create a set in one statement -- new HashSet( Arrays.asList( TAG_PLAY.toLowerCase(), TAG_PASSWORD.toLowerCase(), .... )).

Answer (score 5):

If you're implementing a data structure for string matching, you probably want a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) of some kind.

If you're just looking to do this in Java without heaps of code, chuck all the strings you want to match against in a set and then check whether your target string is in the set.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good candidate for an [enum](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).  A simple example is:

```
public enum TagType
{
  TAG_PLAY,
  TAG_PASSWORD
}
```

However, you can elaborate on this a lot.  Java enums provide the performance of integers (for comparisons) along with the type-safety and behavior of objects.  You wouldn't have to worry about the equivalent of `e.getActionCommand()` not being a valid TAG, since it's type-safe.

Comment: ActionCommand requires a String (unless there is a way to change that), therefore would an enum improve the testing?

Comment: @Jason, I think I misunderstood.  I interpreted "nothing to do with the getActionCommand" as meaning a different API was an option.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, what I meant is that I'm purely talking about comparing strings, and that getaction command was just in the code example I had handy

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
final String upperCaseCommand = e.getActionCommand().toUpperCase();
if(TAG_PLAY.equals(upperCaseCommand)
   ||TAG_PASSWORD.equals(upperCaseCommand)
   ||...
 ){
```

(Of course, the constants also need to be upperCased.

You could also put them in a hash.

```
if (tags.containsKey(upperCaseCommand))
```